# Solving the Basel Problem with Fourier Analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This is problem 1.21 out of Lectures on the Fourier Transform and its Applications by Brad Osgood; we are using the definition of the Fourier series of a function $f(t)$ with period $T$ as

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_ne^{\frac{2\pi int}{T}} \text{ where } c_n = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T f(t)e^{\frac{-2\pi int}{T}}dt$$

In the previous part, I found the Fourier series of $f(t)=t^2$ on $t\in [0,2)$ periodized to have period $T=2$ to be

$$t^2= \frac{4}{3} + \sum_{n\neq0} \left( \frac{-2}{\pi in} + \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2} \right)e^{\pi int}$$

I've verified this with a few colleagues and am confident this is correct. I now need to use this result to solve the Basel problem and show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. I've been given the hint to let $t=0$, which gets close to the answer:

$$0^2= \frac{4}{3} + \sum_{n\neq0} \left( \frac{-2}{\pi in} + \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2} \right)e^{\pi in(0)}$$
$$0=\frac{4}{3} + \sum_{n\neq0} \frac{-2}{\pi in}\cdot 1 + \sum_{n\neq0} \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2}\cdot1$$
$$-\frac{4}{3} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{-2}{\pi in} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi in} + \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2}$$

$$-\frac{4}{3} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi i(-n)} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi in} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi^2(-n)^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2}$$

$$-\frac{4}{3} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi in}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi in} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2}$$

$$-\frac{4}{3} = 0 + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2} = \frac{4}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

$$-\frac{\pi^2}{3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$

But this is incorrect. I feel like saying $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi in} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi in} = 0$ is wrong, because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi in}$ diverges and $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminant. After messing with it, I tried a hack by substituting $x=\sum_{n\neq0} \frac{-2}{\pi in}$ and got the result

$$0=\frac{4}{3} + x + \sum_{n\neq0} \frac{2}{\pi^2n^2} \implies
\frac{-(4+3x)}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Setting $\frac{-(4+3x)}{2}=1$ gives

$$x=\sum_{n\neq0} \frac{-2}{\pi in}=-2$$
$$\sum_{n\neq0} \frac{1}{\pi in}=1$$

Which is telling me something is seriously wrong. I thought I was on the right track because the next part of the problem is to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}$. I can do this by setting $t=1$, assuming $\sum_{n\neq0} \frac{-2}{\pi in}=0$ and doing a similar calculation to what I did above. Does $\sum_{n\neq0} \frac{-2}{\pi in}=0$? If this is actually true, why? What is wrong with my calculation when $t=0$ and how can the hack of $x=-2$ be explained? If not, how can I handle the indeterminant? Is it possible to continue this approach with some modifications? Or is the only way to do this using Parseval's Theorem like in [this similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940827/using-fourier-analysis-to-solve-basel-problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short version.** Your computations are correct ... except the fact that $0^2 = 2$ in this context :-)

---

**Detailed version.** The famous Dirichlet convergence theorem for Fourier series tells that the Fourier series of a function $f$ periodic and piecewise $C^1$ converges to the mean-value of the left and right limits of the function, that is
$$
\tilde{f}(t) = \sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} c_n(f)\,e^{i\pi nt} = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{f(t+\varepsilon)+f(t-\varepsilon)}{2}
$$
In particular, the function defined by $f(t) = t^2$ on $[0,2)$ is discontinuous as a $2$-periodic function on $\Bbb R$, and
$$
\tilde{f}(0) = \frac{2^2 + 0^2}{2} = 2.
$$
This implies
$$
2 = \frac{4}{3} + \sum_{n\neq 0} \frac{2i}{\pi n} + \frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2}.
$$
The $\frac{2i}{\pi n}$ term of the sum is indeed odd, and so vanishes (in the sense of writing the series as a limit of partial sums), and so the equation simplifies to
$$
\frac{1}{3} = \sum_{n\neq 0} \frac{1}{\pi^2 n^2},
$$
which gives the famous
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.
$$